# understanding for loops with reference to list containers in python

Tags: python, list, reference, for-loop

My question is regarding the following for loop:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
for v in x:
  v=[0,0,0]
```

here if you print x you get [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].. so the v changed is not really a reference to the list in x. But when you do something like the following:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
for v in x:
  v[0]=0; v[1]=0; v[2] =0
```

then you get x as [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]. This kinda gets difficult if the list inside x is quite long, and even doing something like this:

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
for v in x:
  for i in v:
    i = 0
```

will give me x as [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]. My best bet is to use *for i in xrange(0,3): v[i]=0* .. Though I'd still like to know what's going on here and what the other alternatives are when I have list of lists or more nested lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When python executes `v = [0, 0, 0]`, it's

1. Creating a new list object with three zeroes in it.
2. Assigning a reference to the new list to a label called `v`

It doesn't matter if `v` was a reference to something else before.

If you want to change the contents of the list currently referenced by `v`, then you can't use the `v =` syntax.  You must assign elements to it, like you mentioned, or use slice notation `v[:] =` as noted by Sven.

Comment: This is a better answer than Sven's because it attempts to explain a bit of what's happening, rather than just giving a recipe to be followed blindly.  (At least, that is all I see in Sven's now; perhaps he will edit it.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so far. So, we are able to mutate the list element `v` is pointing to in the loop body, using `v[:] = ...`, because this list element **is a list itself**. Now, if it would just be an integer or anything else than a list -- is there a way to mutate it without changing the loop header?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Some types, such as int, are immutable.  That means an instance of that type can never change its value.  Common immutable types are numeric types, strings, and tuples.

Answer (score 6):

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
for v in x:
    v[:] = [0,0,0]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Nice :) ... I figured if I have _x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]; x=[x,x]_ .. then -i can use the same aproach at the end of my nested list.. like this: _for v in x: for i in v: i[:]= [0,0,0]_

Comment: @user: Be careful.  When you say `x = [x, x]`, the two elements in the new list have the same identity, so any change you make to one, will affect the other.  (in fact, there is only one)

Comment: sorry I meant maybe `x=[x[:],x[:]]` .I was just lazy when creating the list of list of list of integers